# How to add 2 products to sql at the same time

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 tables:

Table `order:` IDorder, productId, quantity, price

Table `orderdetails:` ID, ShipName, ShipMobile, ShipAddress, ShipEmail, DateOrder.

- My OrderDetailsDao (As Model):

  ```
  raovatmuabanthucungEntities re = null;
  public OrderDetailsDao()
  {
      re = new raovatmuabanthucungEntities();
  }
  public long Insert(orderdetails detail)
  {
      re.orderdetails.Add(order);
      re.SaveChanges();
      return order.ID;
  }
  ```
- My OrderDao:

```html
raovatmuabanthucungEntities re = null;
        public OrderDao()
        {
            re = new raovatmuabanthucungEntities();
        }
        public bool Insert(order order)
        {
            try
            {
                re.order.Add(order);
                re.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

- My Controller:

```html
 public ActionResult Payment(string shipName, string mobile, string address, string email)
        {
            var detail = new orderdetail();
            detail.NgayDatHang = DateTime.Now;
            detail.ShipAddress = address;
            detail.ShipMobile = mobile;
            detail.ShipName = shipName;
            detail.ShipEmail = email;
            try
            {
                var id = new OrderDetailsDao().Insert(detail);
                var cart = (List<CartItem>)Session[CartSession];
                var orderDao = new OrderDao();
                decimal total = 0;
                foreach (var item in cart)
                {
                    var order = new order();
                    order.ProductId= item.Product.ProductId;
                    order.IDOrder = id;
                    order.Price = item.Product.Price;
                    order.quantity = item.quantity;
                    orderDao.Insert(order);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ghi log
                return Redirect("/loi-thanh-toan");
            }
            return Redirect("/hoan-thanh");
        }
```

- I have tried to debug but foreach loop work normaly and return 2 products when i click button PAY. But in my sql server table only 1 record inserted. And `var cart = (List<CartItem>)Session[CartSession];` is my session to save products added to cart. Sorry for disturbing you but i don't know how to fix this. Please tell me if i miss something, i will update my question ... Thank for all.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question, with the emphasis on **minimal**. Also, please write your code in **english**. You may know what a MaSanPham or a SoLuong is, but to a lot of english speakers this is just "random".

Comment: @DavidStockinger do you really need to know what those properties are? They are just properties of that object and highly unlikely to have any bearing on the issue at hand.

Comment: @SeanLange If they are not required, then they should be cut out entirely to create a **minimal** example.

Comment: @DavidStockinger I don't disagree but asking them to change their language is just being rude.

Comment: How many items are in the cart?

Comment: Sorry, i will update

Comment: 2 items but only 1 inserted ...

Comment: look at my answer below.. re.SaveChanges(); is closing your database connection

Comment: @SeanLange Writing in one consistent language is considered good form in almost any community, given that most language keywords are in english as well. And I did not intend to belittle Wiliam - it was merely a friendly suggestion when creating an MCVE.

Comment: That catch inside your Insert method is problematic to say the least. It is using an anti-pattern I refer to as Try/Squelch. If you encounter an error you need to do something with it, not just return false. You are not even looking at the return value of that when you call the Insert method. My guess is that you are getting an error but neatly capturing it and throwing it away. Get rid of that try/catch and set up some break points. Something is breaking there.

Comment: @DavidStockinger I agree that writing in one language is appropriate (and english is the choice on this site). But you were asking them to change their code so the property names are in english. That just seems to be a bit odd to me.

Comment: @SeanLange I asked them to change the code for the MCVE, which should aim to be as minimal as possible. Something as simple as "`object.Property1`" would show that a property is there, but not per sé required for the example. I mean, a function(?) called `raovatmuabanthucungEntities()` is not self-evident to any english speaker. And I feel as if this discussion is slowly getting off-topic. It's Wiliam's choice how they name their properties or how they write their MCVE. All I am suggesting is that a pure-english MCVE might attract more/better answers.

Comment: I have added EntityFramework name : raovatmuabanthucungEntities ... Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in the line mentioned below :

```
order.IDOrder = id;
```

you are trying to insert duplicates into a primary Key field (as communicated by you in messages), so the first time it succeeds to insert value and the second time it fails to do so as duplicate primary keys are not allowed.

Also, re.SaveChanges(); is adding an over-head to your database write operation. It is better if you create an IEnumerable or List of "order" and pass it to Insert() to save all at once.

Change this:

```
    try
    {
        var id = new OrderDetailsDao().Insert(detail);
        var cart = (List<CartItem>)Session[CartSession];
        var orderDao = new OrderDao();
        decimal total = 0;
        foreach (var item in cart)
        {
            var order = new order();
            order.ProductId= item.Product.ProductId;
            order.IDOrder = id;
            order.Price = item.Product.Price;
            order.quantity = item.quantity;
            orderDao.Insert(order);
        }
    }
```

to:

```
    try
    {
        var id = new OrderDetailsDao().Insert(detail);
        var cart = (List<CartItem>)Session[CartSession];
        var orderDao = new OrderDao();
        decimal total = 0;
        List<order> orders = new List<order>();
        foreach (var item in cart)
        {        
            var order = new order();            
            order.ProductId= item.Product.ProductId;
            order.IDOrder = id;
            order.Price = item.Product.Price;
            order.quantity = item.quantity;
            orders.Add(order);
        }
        orderDao.Insert(orders);
    }
```

Also, change this:

```
  public bool Insert(order order)
  {
    try
    {
        re.order.Add(order);
        re.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

to:

```
public bool Insert(List<order> orders)
{
    foreach(var order in orders)
    {
         re.order.Add(order);
    }  
    try
    {               
        re.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you suggest me more detail , i only have 3 hrs left (Deadline) :(

Comment: i will help you brother... please allow me 5 mins. to work on your code.

Comment: Thnk you very much

Comment: i am running =)

Comment: try debugging your code and tell me where it got stuck. I am sure, you have inserted something 'wrong' into the database.

Comment: yes absolutely.. you can not have duplicates in primary key field. ;-)

Comment: Oh oh, my fault :(